# Delete document from Elasticsearch synchronously

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I am using olivere/elastic to work with elasticsearch in Go.
Here is my code:

```
// (1) delete document 
_, err := e.client.Delete().Index(index).Type("entity").
    Id(id).Do(e.ctx)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

// (2) get all documents 
result, err := e.client.Search().Index(index).From(1).Size(100).Do(e.ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(result.TotalHits())

// (3) wait
time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

// (4) get all documents
result, err = e.client.Search().Index(index).From(1).Size(100).Do(e.ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(result.TotalHits())
```

Here I am:

- delete document
- get all documents from collection
- wait 3 seconds
- get the same documents from collection

Now on the step (2) I get one more document than step (4).
Looks like the document is deleted in Elastic with some delay and I am searching the way to delete the document synchronously.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html. Note that many requests with ?refresh can cause serious performance issues.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please create the answer.

Comment: Nah. I don't know the package, so I can't write an adequate answer. You can do it yourself though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_, err := e.client.Delete().Index(index).Type("entity").
    Id(id).Refresh("true").Do(e.ctx)
```

**Refresh("true")**